# How can I remove the youtube branding completely from embedded video?

Tags: video, youtube

I have tried to embed videos without youtube branding because it sends my traffic to youtube. I set `modestbranding=1` and `showinfo=0` but I still see a youtube branding in bottom of the player when I hover the cursor on player.

When I got this I thought, I can't remove that from embedded video but when I came through a site yesterday, I found that their embedding doesn't have youtube branding. They removed that entirely.

If you want that site link here it is http://vitaminl.tv/video/1072?ref=rcm

Can anyone please help me how can I do that? I know we can remove youtube branding using jwplayer but I like to have my own code and design for my site. Help me to solve this.

PS - I am using wordpress.

Comment: to date; this worked out for me; keep showinfo=1 otherwise it won't work hope someone input in removing both title and branding [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46941510/7735285)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Since this is quite an old post and i'm getting downvotes on it as the solution doesn't work anymore, the simple answer is (as of early 2017):
**You can NOT completely remove the youtube branding.**

You can play around with setting:
`modestbranding=1` - to remove the youtube logo 
and
`showinfo=0` to remove the title and uploader info

Although with `modestbranding` set to `1` *you will still get a small youtube text label*.

For more info check out Google developers' site:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

---

**Old answer from 2013:**

As you can see they use:

```
showinfo=0
iv_load_policy=3
modestbranding=1
nologo=1
```

The last one seems interesting :)

`iv_load_policy=3` means the use of HTML5 if I'm correct

Comment: This one is worked very well. can you help me how to remove "watch later" from embed player? Tried probably_logged_in=0 but not working.

Comment: Not working. This still shows the watermark and the 'nologo' parameter doesn't even exist: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: Unfortunately this is the "solution" I found, too. There is no real ("legit") way to remove the branding completely, since YouTube wants to at least show one kind of logo on the player.

Comment: `showinfo` is deprecated and ignored starting September 25, 2018. https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#showinfo

Answer (score 4):

As of April 2018 - Here are the results I'm getting

`showinfo=0` removes the title from top left and share and watch later icons from top left

`modestbranding=0` will make the YouTube logo disappear from the CONTROLS when the video is playing, but there will be a YouTube logo in the bottom right of the video and video poster (when not playing).

`modestbranding=1` will make it NOT display the YouTube logo on the video poster, but will make it appear in the control bar instead.

If you turn off controls (`controls=0`) then the permanent YouTube watermark will appear on the bottom right (same as turning off `modestbranding`), regardless of what is set for `modestbranding`.

Kind of an interesting mix of options that aren't well explained or documented, especially since turning modest branding "off" actually adds permanent YouTube branding on the video even when not playing (much strong branding in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

The most you can hide is using `controls=0`.
The argument `"ps=docs"` can hide the youtube clickable logo when mouseover, but doesn't do anything if using `control=0`.

[showinfo=0&controls=0](http://www.youtube.com/embed/1V0Pt-aSPQE?showinfo=0&controls=0)

[showinfo=0&ps=docs](http://www.youtube.com/embed/1V0Pt-aSPQE?showinfo=0&ps=docs)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont ajust the height, the youtube logo does not show

```
<iframe width="728" height="410" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PJ_fFrdSKlg?showinfo=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;nologo=1&amp;autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1">
                    </iframe>
```