# Embedded YouTube video modestbranding=1 not working with showinfo=0 in android?

Tags: android, html, iframe, webview, youtube

I want to display YouTube video in my android application with the parameter modestbranding=1 and showinfo=0 in webview. When I tried this,then modestbranding doesn't work any more.

if i remove showinfo then modestbranding parameter is working and vice versa.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/ANdeRJF7MWo?modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&rel=0

I search alot but did not find its solution. Please help

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: facing same problem anyone have solution to hide other details.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the IFrame player docs with the [**officially supported parameters**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters) along with [revision history](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Revision_History)

> - `modestbranding` -  This parameter lets you use a YouTube player that does not show a YouTube logo. Set the parameter value to 1 to prevent the YouTube logo from displaying in the control bar. Note that a small YouTube text label will still display in the upper-right corner of a paused video when the user's mouse pointer hovers over the player.
> - `showinfo` - was deprecated in 2018

**See Also**:

- [modestbranding not working for YouTube embed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40353582/1366033)
- [About Youtube iframe caption ,title, modestbranding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64780850/1366033)
- [How can I remove the youtube branding completely from embedded video?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20099545/1366033)