# modestbranding not working for YouTube embed

Tags: youtube, embed

I'm trying to hide the YouTube logo that appears in the bottom right had corner of an embed. For some reason modestbranding=1 is not working:

```
<iframe class="gtms-intro" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ywFGJecodxQ?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;playlist=ywFGJecodxQ" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: August 15, 2023: [The modestbranding parameter is deprecated and will have no effect. To align with YouTube's branding requirements, the player now determines the appropriate branding treatment based on a combination of factors, including player size, other API parameters (e.g. controls), and additional signals.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_15_2023)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is with how you added the parameters. Inside the link you are supposed to add parameters like so:

```
"http://www.myLink.com?first_param=1&second_param=0&third_param=3"
```

No `amp;` in between.
As a result, your iFrame is supposed to look like this:

```
<iframe class="gtms-intro" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ywFGJecodxQ?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&modestbranding=1&playlist=ywFGJecodxQ" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: It's the other way around, in HTML you should encode ´&´ as ´&amp;´

Note that chrome dev tools hide the fact that the string is encoded.

Comment: in my tests, `modestbranding` does nothing. only `controls` has any effect.

Answer (score 18):

Combination of `controls=0` and `modestbranding=1` also gives a big YouTube logo at the right bottom corner. `showinfo` does nothing anymore since September 2018.

Comment: Yea, it's not officially documented, but `controls=0` and `modestbranding=1` don't seem to co-exist (`modestbranding` gets over-ridden to `0`).

Comment: in my tests, `modestbranding=1` does nothing. only `controls=0` has any effect.

Answer (score 12):

If you have `showinfo=0` at the same time as `modestbranding=1` the YouTube logo will show even more prominent.

My conclusion is that there is no way to remove all links to youtube so you have to pick one.

These images show the visual when playing.

```
showinfo=0&modestbranding=0
```

[image]

```
showinfo=0&modestbranding=1
```

[image: Hide info modestbranding]

```
showinfo=1&modestbranding=1
```

[image: showinfo hide logo]

Comment: Google has altered the deal.  Pray they don't alter it further.

Answer (score 9):

I just noticed modestbranding stopped working for me when I added color=white but when I turned it to color=red the YT logo disappeared. Hope it helps someone with a similar issue.

Comment: Wow! Yep, you are right. I have had color=white... Many, many thanks...

Comment: Unfortunately intended behavior. In the docs it says "Note: Setting the color parameter to white will disable the modestbranding option."

Comment: if one looking for [doc link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#color)

Answer (score 1):

This is already deprecated and will no longer works.

"August 15, 2023
Note: This is a deprecation announcement for the modestbranding parameter.

The modestbranding parameter is deprecated and will have no effect. To align with YouTube's branding requirements, the player now determines the appropriate branding treatment based on a combination of factors, including player size, other API parameters (e.g. controls), and additional signals."

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#august-15,-2023

Answer (score 0):

This url is working fine for me.

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoId?modestbranding=1&enablejsapi=1&widgetid=3&iv_load_policy=3&fs=0
```

Where `videoId` is the youtube id you can pass it dynmically.

Hope it helps to someone.

Answer (score 0):

`modestbranding` has been deprecated and no longer works as per [Google's announcement](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_15_2023)