# Hiding YouTube embed title and 'More videos' (Updated)

Tags: youtube-iframe-api, youtubeplayer

Is there an official way to hide the title and the `More videos` section from a YouTube embed (**latest version as of July 2nd 2018**), and just show the YouTube logo bottom-right? I know the embed used to have this ability some time ago.

What I'm basically looking for is have the embed auto play with no other elements on it except the mandatory YouTube logo and be able to pause it, but no `More videos` appear when doing that.

For the `showinfo` option, the documentation currently says:

> Setting the parameter's value to 0 causes the player to not display
>   information like the video title and uploader `before` the video starts
>   playing.

So that `before` clearly says that this does not take effect during the video play.

But is there any way to hide the Uploader, Title, Watch Later and Share buttons from the top part of an embed?

This is how it currently looks when the video is paused:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dnmJLVWetQM?autoplay=1&controls=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" title="YouTube video player" width="720" height="405">
```

[image]

Also the comment from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51068917/1959596) is not up to date anymore.

For the `rel` option, the documentation currently says:

> This parameter indicates whether the player should show related videos when playback of the initial video ends.

So this too doesn't apply when the video is paused.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: The only solution is to use another video platform for hosting your content if you need a chrome-less player. Developers should be outraged over this move. In other words? YouTube wants their embed player to be used as a consumer product only.

Comment: I've written a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893902/how-to-remove-youtube-branding-after-embedding-video-in-web-page/56060367#56060367

Answer (score 18, accepted):

YouTube deprecated parameter `showinfo` (can no more hide title) and changed parameter `rel` behavior (will show related videos).

Details in https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018

> Note: This is a deprecation announcement for the showinfo parameter. In addition, the behavior for the rel parameter is changing. Titles, channel information, and related videos are an important part of YouTube’s core user experience, and these changes help to make the YouTube viewing experience consistent across different platforms.

Comment: Developers should be outraged over this move. In other words? YouTube wants their embed player to be used as a consumer product only. As if to say they have the greatest platform in the world and no developer should ever have a need for a chrome-less player. Meantime, despite all their money, Vimeo's player FAR surpasses them in quality.

Comment: This is infuriating on their part, but thank you for finding the relevant release notes. At least now we know, instead of tearing our hair out wondering why the embeds don't look the same.

Comment: That's a ridiculous move, whenever devs are going to use background videos they will be basically forced to use competitors...