# How to remove signin button from youtube video in swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I am new in swift and I am getting problem in removing sign in button from youtube video

my code is like this

```
var videoUrl = vedioarr1[indexPath.row] as? String
videoUrl = (videoUrl ?? "")
print(videoUrl)

let youtubeUrl = URL(string: videoUrl ?? "")!
let youtubeRequest = URLRequest(url: youtubeUrl ?? URL(string: "")!)                    
cell.youtubeWebView.load(youtubeRequest)
```

VedioUrl contains url 
YoutubeWebView is WKWebView

[image]

I Just want to remove sign in button

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cKdlhaQrGo
```

Comment: there is **no key** to remove the signinbutton. see this for example : [YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to embed a youtube video, Youtube has an embed URL for it. You just need to get the videoID and create your URL.

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cKdlhaQrGo` this is the URL you are currently using. The ID after `watch?v=` is the videoID. In your case, the videoID is `7cKdlhaQrGo`.

Now you can create your URL like this:

```
let myURL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cKdlhaQrGo"

let youtubeEmbedURL = myURL.replacingOccurrences(of: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", with: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/") 

let youtubeRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: youtubeEmbedURL)!)  

cell.youtubeWebView.load(youtubeRequest)
```

This will remove the signing button and make sure only video shows up in whole screen.

Update2:

If you want to disable controls, you can add this string to your url,

```
let youtubeEmbedURL = myURL.replacingOccurrences(of: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", with: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/") + "?rel=0?version=3&autoplay=1&controls=0&&showinfo=0&loop=1" // this string will disable controls.
```

But you can not disable title.

YouTube deprecated parameter showinfo (can no more hide title) and changed parameter rel behavior (will show related videos).

Details in https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018

> Note: This is a deprecation announcement for the showinfo parameter.
>   In addition, the behavior for the rel parameter is changing. Titles,
>   channel information, and related videos are an important part of
>   YouTube’s core user experience, and these changes help to make the
>   YouTube viewing experience consistent across different platforms.

Actual answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52767228/8374890

Comment: check if youtubeEmbedURL url is correct. https://www.youtube.com/embed/7cKdlhaQrGo . You can directly open it in chrome too, it does loads. check your code again

Comment: Sign in button is removed but showing Title and watch latter and share button

Comment: Nothing change and my mobile is getting hang

Comment: There is no way this code would crash your device. You are doing anything wrong. Please check :) or paste your view controller code here.

Comment: But it depends where have you paste your code. if the code is being called again and again.

Comment: its in collection view cell

Answer (score 2):

Instead of  loading a request, load HTML string as:

```
let ytEmbedString = "<iframe id='ytplayer' type='text/html' width='640' height='360' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com' frameborder='0'></iframe>"

cell.youtubeWebView.loadHTMLString(ytEmbedString, baseURL: nil)
```

Check YouTube docs for more details on embedding.