# How to disable/prevent redirects in an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, ejs, embed

**We have the following two iFrames:**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DmiMpABb804" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

```
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/39LLxExYz6ewLAcYrzQQyP" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

The YouTube iFrame has, "Watch on YouTube" at the bottom left corner. This redirects the user to YouTube.

The Spotify iFrame has the 'Spotify logo' on top right corner, that redirects the user to Spotify.

***Our Aim: Nothing happens when the user clicks/taps on either of these.***

---

Directly open the embed players here:

- https://www.youtube.com/embed/DmiMpABb804
- https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/39LLxExYz6ewLAcYrzQQyP

Comment: This can't be controlled from our side. You'd need to check YT and Spotify's documentation for that. You can use [modest branding for YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#modestbranding) but with the some [conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353582/modestbranding-not-working-for-youtube-embed).

Comment: @omkarbhagat Okay. I wasn't aware of modest branding, thank you for educating me. Can't we do something to completely block our website from redirecting? It's harsh actually. Is there a way to restrict certain divs from redirecting?

Comment: @omkarbhagat Perhaps block redirects to certain domains?

Answer (score -1):

You can check out a video CDN service called Swarmify, and I think more video CDN's are working on this, but Swarmify (I have no affiliation) essentially recode and host the video which is not ideal for all.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33091634)