# About Youtube iframe caption ,title, modestbranding problem

Tags: iframe, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Sorry, English is not my first language.
Have anyone can provide the above solution?
I want to hide the caption from my iframe
[here's my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UstEr.jpg)
but I tested to set the "cc_load_policy = 0or 3",it doesn't work
and also I wanna hide the title and youtube logo, I did it but it still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some YouTube player parameters:

- For the top info bar: Since late 2018, YouTube removed the `showinfo` parameter, making the top info bar mandatory.
- For the related videos: Since late 2018, YouTube changed the `rel` parameter to show videos from the same channel instead of turning off related videos completely. The `rel` parameter isn't deprecated, it just has a new meaning.
- For the controls: Set `controls` to 0.
- For the YouTube logo: Set `modestbranding` to 1.
- For the fullscreen button: Set `fs` to 0.
- For the progress bar color: Set `color` to white to change the progress bar color to white. Note that the `color` and `modestbranding` options cannot coexist.

For example, to get related videos from the same channel and minimal controls:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/K-a8s8OLBSE?rel=0&modestbranding=1&fs=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If you'd like more control over your video player, it would be better to self-host your videos. Then you are in full control of the player. Note that if it's not your video, you must ask permission before doing that.

For an example, see [this page](https://techboyg5blog.com/g5-static/stackoverflow/minimal-youtube-player.php), because YouTube embeds don't seem to work properly in Stack Overflow code snippets.

Comment: Thanks my friend, I have a new solution. But I also want to know you mentioned that is the self-host video?