# Disable YouTube logo on embeded video

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

I embeded a youtube video via iframe but &modestbranding=1 does not work if &controls is set to 0.

```
<iframe style="display: block; margin: auto;" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9dUdfY7op6M?modestbranding=1&controls=0&color=white&showinfo=0&disablekb=1&rel=0&autohide=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I've tried assigning display: none; to .ytp-watermark class and i've tried to find class with JS and then x[0].style.display="none", but neither of them worked.

Is there any other way I can remove the logo?

Comment: you cannot apply style to element inside the iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `showinfo=0` to remove the title from the top of the embedded

video, `modestbranding=1` will not work, and the logo will appear.

```html
<iframe style="display: block; margin: auto;" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9dUdfY7op6M" modestbranding=1 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: +1, it worked and its accepted the title bar, but the logo was so big and its not showing now....I saw some down vote on this answer; even though there is a working fiddle! strange and disturbing!