# Youtube embed showing unwanted topbar even with showinfo=0

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api, embed

I am displaying an embed YouTube video as a background of a section. The problem is that the video should not show any YouTube informations, but it shows the video's logo and title briefly, resulting in a problematic display with the website's design (In the image you can see the video's logo and title appearing behind the website's logo):

[image: The YouTube video logo appears behind the website logo]

The generated link in the iframe is:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/67jdk5q3BaY?
iv_load_policy=3
&modestbranding=1
&autoplay=1
&controls=0
&showinfo=0
&wmode=transparent
&branding=0
&autohide=1
&rel=0
&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fads-up.fr
&disablekb=1
&fs=0
&enablejsapi=1
&widgetid=2
```

The iframe code:

```
<iframe id="YTPlayer-ID-1540117232090" class="ytplayer-player-inline" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" title="YouTube video player" width="1585" height="892" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/67jdk5q3BaY?iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;branding=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;rel=0&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fads-up.fr&amp;disablekb=1&amp;fs=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;widgetid=2" style="width: 1585px; height: 892px; left: 0px; top: -256px;"></iframe>
```

I tried changing the modestbranding value but it's not working.

Comment: Have you tried tried the option given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49807266/8342742)?

Comment: Thanks, yes I have tried that, it's not working. I think I've checked and tried everything available and apparently it's currently not possible... We have to wait for Google to provide a new option or change provider!

Comment: I've ended up using a negative top margin to hide the top bar for now...

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, youtube has recently changed the behavior of their API.

showinfo=0 does not work anymore.

See: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#showinfo

> Note: This parameter is deprecated and will be ignored after September 25, 2018.

Comment: Note: Only the English documentation page shows the depreciation notice. The french version did not show it...